# Is there a way for this script to only provide a summary of events where the event summary is unique?

Tags: python, loops

I am looking to provide a summary count of unique events where an attendee does not contain a domain.com email address. I have the list of events and each attendee, but the script is pulling out two calendar summary for each attendee.

```
for calendar_id in me:
        eventsResult = service.events().list(
            calendarId=calendar_id,
            timeMax=now,
            timeMin=end_date).execute()

        events = service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_id).execute()
        events = events.get('items', [])

        for event in events:

            if 'attendees' in event.keys():
                for attendees in event['attendees']:
                    atte = attendees.get('email')
                    try:
                        attid = event.get(attendees)
                    except:
                        pass
                        if "domain.com" not in atte:
                            print('\n' + event['summary'] + " " + "(Calendar - " + calendar_id + ")")
                            print(attendees['email'])
                        else:
                            continue
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pulling out two calendar summary"? What is the output you expected and what do you get instead?

Comment: I am basically just getting two of these responses:

PM Team Meeting.  (Calendar - email@email.com)
email@email.com

PM Team Meeting.  (Calendar - email@email.com)
email@email.com

I only want one entry for the Calendar event.

Comment: You have a loop `for attendees in event['attendees']`. Apparently you are seeing two iterations of this loop. Why do you think that the number of iterations should be different than two?